# Regular expression for XML tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, rubular

I am having a hard time matching the following text:

```
<Reports>
   <Report active="1" valid="1" bureau="EXS"> Dummy Dummy</Report>
</Reports>
```

Using the following Regex:

```
/<Reports>.*<\/Reports>/
```

I am using rubular (I am using ruby) to test it , but I don't understand why my RegEx fails.

```
http://rubular.com/r/QEhgQ9Vgla
```

Any help?

Comment: obligatory link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?page=1&tab=oldest#tab-top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include multiline modifier `m`.

```
/<Reports>.*<\/Reports>/m
```

[DEMO](http://rubular.com/r/fDqzUXcta2)

Answer (score 0):

You could solve the problem with the help of [`REXML`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/rexml/rdoc/REXML/Document.html) library.

```
require 'rexml/document.rb'

doc = REXML::Document.new <<-DOC
<Reports>
   <Report active="1" valid="1" bureau="EXS"> Dummy Dummy</Report>
</Reports>
DOC

doc.get_text("/Reports/Report") # => " Dummy Dummy"
```